# oracle | merge data where row not matches the primary key that inserted

Tags: oracle, merge

I have tow users in oracle

1. nsrtax = target
2. temp_nsrtax = source

the schema for the  tables are the same

```
Name       Type         
---------- ------------  
CUSTNO     NUMBER(10)                             
EKRARYEAR  NUMBER(4)                              
ESALNO     NUMBER(10)                             
EKRARDATE  DATE                                  
EKRARFROM  DATE                                  
EKRARTO    DATE                                  
TOTALEKRAR NUMBER(15,3)                          
TOTALSARF  NUMBER(15,3)                          
EQUAL1     NUMBER(15,3)                          
DEPTNO     NUMBER(4)                              
JEBAYA     NUMBER(1)    
USERIN     NUMBER(3)                             
USERUP     NUMBER(3)                             
PRODATE    DATE                                  
STATE      NUMBER(1)    
REGNO      NUMBER(2)                              
BRNO       NUMBER(3)                              
EKRARNO    NUMBER(4)                              
EKRARTYPE  NUMBER(1)                              
EK_LOSS    NUMBER(15,3) 
TYPESTAXE  NUMBER(10)   
EXEMPT     NUMBER(10,3)
```

there is primary key  `PR_TAWTEEK primary key (CUSTNO, EKRARYEAR, ESALNO, EKRARTYPE)` in both tables

i just create the merge code like this

```
 MERGE INTO TA_TAWTEEK D    USING (SELECT CUSTNO,EKRARYEAR,ESALNO,EKRARDATE,EKRARFROM,EKRARTO,TOTALEKRAR,TOTALSARF,EQUAL1,DEPTNO,JEBAYA,USERIN,USERUP,PRODATE,STATE,REGNO,BRNO,EKRARNO,EKRARTYPE,EK_LOSS,TYPESTAXE,EXEMPT            
FROM temp_nsrtax.TA_TAWTEEK 
WHERE custno=26 ) S  
 ON (D.custno = S.custno) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
 (D.CUSTNO,D.EKRARYEAR,D.ESALNO,D.EKRARDATE,D.EKRARFROM,
 D.EKRARTO,D.TOTALEKRAR,D.TOTALSARF,D.EQUAL1,D.DEPTNO,D.JEBAYA,
 D.USERIN,D.USERUP,D.PRODATE,D.STATE,D.REGNO,D.BRNO,D.EKRARNO,
 D.EKRARTYPE,D.EK_LOSS,D.TYPESTAXE,D.EXEMPT )
VALUES(S.CUSTNO,S.EKRARYEAR,S.ESALNO,S.EKRARDATE,S.EKRARFROM
 ,S.EKRARTO,S.TOTALEKRAR,
 S.TOTALSARF,S.EQUAL1,S.DEPTNO,S.JEBAYA,S.USERIN,S.USERUP,S.PRODATE,
 S.STATE,S.REGNO,S.BRNO,S.EKRARNO,S.EKRARTYPE,S.EK_LOSS,S.TYPESTAXE,
 S.EXEMPT)S.CUSTNO,S.EKRARYEAR,S.ESALNO,S.EKRARDATE,
 S.EKRARFROM,S.EKRARTO,S.TOTALEKRAR,S.TOTALSARF,S.EQUAL1,
 S.DEPTNO,S.JEBAYA,S.USERIN,S.USERUP,S.PRODATE,S.STATE,S.REGNO,
 S.BRNO,S.EKRARNO,S.EKRARTYPE,S.EK_LOSS,S.TYPESTAXE,S.EXEMPT
```

but it doesn't work as i need , i need to insert all rows in the target where the the primary key columns not MATCHED , not when all the Rows not MATCHED

*Sorry for my bad English !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

First, the `MATCHED` and `NOT MATCHED` sections correspond with the condition from the `USING ... ON <condition>` clause. So if you want to say "NOT MATCHED (CUSTNO, EKRARYEAR, ESALNO, EKRARTYPE)", you need to include all those columns in your join condition, like this:

```
MERGE INTO TA_TAWTEEK D    USING (SELECT CUSTNO,EKRARYEAR,ESALNO,EKRARDATE,EKRARFROM,EKRARTO,TOTALEKRAR,TOTALSARF,EQUAL1,DEPTNO,JEBAYA,USERIN,USERUP,PRODATE,STATE,REGNO,BRNO,EKRARNO,EKRARTYPE,EK_LOSS,TYPESTAXE,EXEMPT            
FROM temp_nsrtax.TA_TAWTEEK 
WHERE custno=26 ) S  
 ON (D.custno = S.custno 
    AND D.EKRARYEAR = S.EKRARYEAR 
    AND D.ESALNO = S.ESALNO
    AND D.EKRARTYPE = S.EKRARTYPE) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
 (D.CUSTNO,D.EKRARYEAR,D.ESALNO,D.EKRARDATE,D.EKRARFROM,
 D.EKRARTO,D.TOTALEKRAR,D.TOTALSARF,D.EQUAL1,D.DEPTNO,D.JEBAYA,
 D.USERIN,D.USERUP,D.PRODATE,D.STATE,D.REGNO,D.BRNO,D.EKRARNO,
 D.EKRARTYPE,D.EK_LOSS,D.TYPESTAXE,D.EXEMPT )
VALUES(S.CUSTNO,S.EKRARYEAR,S.ESALNO,S.EKRARDATE,S.EKRARFROM
 ,S.EKRARTO,S.TOTALEKRAR,
 S.TOTALSARF,S.EQUAL1,S.DEPTNO,S.JEBAYA,S.USERIN,S.USERUP,S.PRODATE,
 S.STATE,S.REGNO,S.BRNO,S.EKRARNO,S.EKRARTYPE,S.EK_LOSS,S.TYPESTAXE,
 S.EXEMPT)S.CUSTNO,S.EKRARYEAR,S.ESALNO,S.EKRARDATE,
 S.EKRARFROM,S.EKRARTO,S.TOTALEKRAR,S.TOTALSARF,S.EQUAL1,
 S.DEPTNO,S.JEBAYA,S.USERIN,S.USERUP,S.PRODATE,S.STATE,S.REGNO,
 S.BRNO,S.EKRARNO,S.EKRARTYPE,S.EK_LOSS,S.TYPESTAXE,S.EXEMPT
```

Second, if you're only doing an INSERT, then you don't need a merge at all, and the syntax is simpler:

```
INSERT INTO TA_TAWTEEK (CUSTNO,EKRARYEAR,ESALNO,EKRARDATE,EKRARFROM,
 EKRARTO,TOTALEKRAR,TOTALSARF,EQUAL1,DEPTNO,JEBAYA,
 USERIN,USERUP,PRODATE,STATE,REGNO,BRNO,EKRARNO,
 EKRARTYPE,EK_LOSS,TYPESTAXE,EXEMPT )
SELECT CUSTNO,EKRARYEAR,ESALNO,EKRARDATE,EKRARFROM,
 EKRARTO,TOTALEKRAR,TOTALSARF,EQUAL1,DEPTNO,JEBAYA,
 USERIN,USERUP,PRODATE,STATE,REGNO,BRNO,EKRARNO,
 EKRARTYPE,EK_LOSS,TYPESTAXE,EXEMPT            
FROM temp_nsrtax.TA_TAWTEEK S
WHERE custno=26  
 AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from TA_TAWTEEK D where D.custno = S.custno 
    AND D.EKRARYEAR = S.EKRARYEAR 
    AND D.ESALNO = S.ESALNO
    AND D.EKRARTYPE = S.EKRARTYPE)
;
```